# How to join and extract in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like below

①first, I would like to join tables to `T3`

`T1`

```
product  customer
A        A
B        A
C        B
B        B
A        C
B        C
.        .
.        .
.        .
```

`T2`

```
customer area
A         X
B         Y
C         Z
・　　　　・
・　　　　・
```

`T3`

```
product  customer area
A        A        X
B        A        X
C        B        Y
B        B        Y 
A        C        Z
B        C        Z
.        .　　　　 ・
.        .　　　　 ・
.        .
```

②second I would like to extract customer who has `product`=`A`

`T4`

```
product  customer  area
A        A          X
B        A          X
A        C          Z
B        C          Z
.        .　　　　  ・
.        .　　　　  ・
.        .
```

③ third, I would like to `pivot`them by `count`

```
product\area  X  Y 
A
B
C
```

Are there any way to aggregate this ? My attempt is like this. 
But this is not included `join process` and pivot

```
    WITH T AS (
    SELECT t.*,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN product = 'A' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY customer) AS a_cnt
    FROM T1 t
)

SELECT product, customer
FROM T
WHERE a_cnt > 0;
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "pivot by count"?  There is no "count" in your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select customer,
       sum(case when area = 'X' then 1 else 0 end) as x,
       sum(case when area = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as y
from t1
where exists (select 1
              from t1 tt1
              where tt1.customer = t1.customer and tt1.product = 'A'
             )
group by customer;
```