# How to join and grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like below

And ,I would like to get `T4`

①first, I would like to join tables to T3

`T1`

```
product  customer
A        A
B        A
C        B
B        B
A        C
B        C
.        .
.        .
.        .
```

`T2`

```
customer area
A         X
B         Y
C         Z
・　　　　・
・　　　　・
```

`T3`

```
product  customer area
A        A        X
B        A        X
C        B        Y
B        B        Y 
A        C        Z
B        C        Z
.        .　　　　 ・
.        .　　　　 ・
.        .
```

②second I would like to extract customer who has `product=A`

`T4`

```
product  customer  area
A        A          X
B        A          X
A        C          Z
B        C          Z
.        .　　　　  ・
.        .　　　　  ・
.        .
```

Are there any method for this?

Thanks

Comment: How is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60965038/how-to-join-and-extract-in-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the inner join between T1 and T2 to create the T3 and then use the T3 and T1 to fetch T4 as follows:

```
-- CREATING T3
SELECT
    T1.PRODUCT,
    T1.CUSTOMER,
    T2.AREA
FROM
    T1
    JOIN T2 ON T1.CUSTOMER = T2.CUSTOMER; 

-- QUERY FOR T4 USING T3 AND T1
SELECT
      T3.*
  FROM
      T3
  WHERE
      EXISTS (
          SELECT
              1
          FROM
              T1
          WHERE
              T1.CUSTOMER = T3.CUSTOMER
              AND T1.PRODUCT = 'A'
      );
```